# how do i consolidate all x unit projects under a single folder in order to add the o one single source control?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing, xunit, visual-studio-2019

I am using `visual studio 2019` to create simple `asp.net 2.1 mvc` project. I have added two more `xunit` projects in the same solution as the mvc project. However, I want to add all these projects to a single source control such as `Github`. But when I try to add a source control it gives me the following warning:

> The current solution has a project that is located outside of the solution folder. These project will not be source controlled in a git repository.

My question is how do I get to consolidate all the project under a single folder and the solution does not break?

Comment: Just copy it to solution folder

Comment: @Pavel  Anikhouski, thank  you for the hint. I realized I was placing my solution and project in the same directory , so now I have a folder with the same name as the project that I am working on and I can nest more projects that can be source controlled.. thank you